# Trusty with Xenial kernel locks on boot. AMD A8-6500 APU

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, lockup

Tried installing the latest HWE on Trusty, but once installed I boot to a black screen and the system is unresponsive.  Using GRUB I can successfully boot with the prior 4.2 kernel.  System is an HP Pavilion P7-1235 with 16Gb RAM and an AMD A8-6500 quad core processor.  What information can I gather so you might be able to assist?

Answer (score 1):

I never found out what was causing the problem HOWEVER once I uninstalled the Cinnamon and LXDE desktops from my system, it booted up just fine with the most recent 4.4 kernel.